# Multiple FDR corrected experiments using the same data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I am testing many (500,000) genetic variants, and the tests are FDR corrected and give me a q-value. Normally I would just call everything with q < .05 significant.
But in this case I am testing those same genetic variants in two other related experiments (not using exactly the same individuals, but the samples may overlap). What to do? Would changing the significance threshold for q to .05/3=.0167 be an option? Many thanks!

Comment: Is it the same phenotype in the three experiments?

Comment: Thank for the motivation. This question led me to writing this manuscript:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4920

Comment: Nice! There wasn't really a phenotype by the way, this question was about the paragraphs "Selection pressures as a source of genetic differentiation" in this paper: http://www.tweelingenregister.org/nederlands/verslaggeving/NTR-publicaties_2013/Abdellaoui_EJHG_2013_epub.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer would depend on how you measure errors (and their proportions).
If you are concerned with the proportion of false discoveries within each experiment, then do separate FDR corrections. If you are worried about the "global" proportion of false discoveries, you could treat all the experiments as one. This would guarantee Global FDR control, but the FDR within each experiment is NOT controlled for. 
I believe your suggestion is a conservative way to get FDR control at both levels: within each experiment and globally.

Comment: Would it be justifiable to perform apply a less conservative control of FDR at each level independently?  ie. to first adjust p-values with the B-H procedure over the three tests for each variant, and then apply the same method to further adjust those adjusted values for all the variants, for each test?