# When to apply FDR procedure when doing many t-tests for many dependent variables?

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I'm looking to run a bunch of t-tests, and I'm trying to figure out the appropriate time to apply an FDR correction.

I have four conditions and am doing pairwise comparisons amongst these conditions, so I have six pairwise comparisons/t-tests to run on each variable. I have 30 variables.

Does it make more sense to:

- Do all of the pairwise t-tests, take all of the p-values, and perform one FDR correction?
  I.e.: I have 6 p-values (6 pairwise comparisons) for the 30 variables and run **one FDR correction** on the 180 p-values?
- Or to perform an FDR correction for each pairwise t-test for each variable?
  I.e.: Run an FDR correction for the 6 p-values for each variable, for a total of **30 FDR corrections**.

ETA:

To clarify, my variables are not dependent (my title was edited)--perhaps 'variables' is not the correct term. I am looking at changes in gene expression for 30 different unrelated genes. The conditions are the same for each gene though. So for gene 1, I am running pairwise t-tests for condition A vs B, A vs C, A vs D, B vs C, B vs D, and C vs D, and then repeating this for each gene.

I've just noticed this question, in which the asker has a similar set-up to me:
[Multiple testing and FDR on multiple-pairs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44077/multiple-testing-and-fdr-on-multiple-pairs?rq=1)

I hadn't thought about running FDR for each pairwise comparison (**6 FDR corrections** for my case), though I'm not sure this would be the best option. Advice?

Answer (score 1):

Benjamini-Hochberg procedure (FDR) generally assumes tests are independent from each other (but see [this](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~ybenja/MyPapers/benjamini_yekutieli_ANNSTAT2001.pdf)), so it may not be an ideal test for among-conditions assessment (the 6 pairwise comparisons). Otherwise, 'to run a bunch of tests' sounds like a single-family/question approach so you'd need to apply correction to the entire population of p-values generated. In other words, you just set your bet 180 times, chances you 'win' in this roulette are quite a bit higher than if you were to set 1 bet. A more cohesive design e.g. a two-way ANOVA with Tukey-Kramer post-hoc comparisons, assuming the 4 conditions are the same throughout, would be much preferred.

Comment: BH does allow for certain types of dependence!

Comment: @ChristophHanck - ok, clarified

Comment: To clarify, my variables are not dependent (my title was edited)--perhaps 'variables' is not the correct term. I am looking at changes in gene expression for 30 different unrelated genes. The conditions are the same for each gene though. So for gene 1, I am running pairwise t-tests for condition A vs B, A vs C, A vs D, B vs C, B vs D, and C vs D, and then repeating this for each gene.

Comment: Note also the paper: Joseph P. Romano · Azeem M. Shaikh · Michael Wolf: "Control of the false discovery rate under dependence using the bootstrap and subsampling."  Test (2008) 17: 417–442.  The simulation results that are reported there suggest that BH is effective under quite general correlation structures.  Not a proof, but BH seems clearly hard to break